# Adding hyperlink to an image from function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a VBA function to add an image from the file path and add a hyperlink to it.
It needs to be called from a function, it can't be a Sub.

```vb
Function AddHyperlinkedImage()
    InsertPictureHyperlink
End Function


Sub InsertPictureHyperlink()
    Dim pct As Picture, iLeft#, iTop#
    Dim sFile As String
    sFile = "C:\somepath\picture.jpg"
    If Dir(sFile) = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With Range("A1")
        .Select
        iLeft = .Left: iTop = .Top
    End With
    Set pct = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(sFile)
    pct.Left = iLeft
    pct.Top = iTop
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Shapes(pct.Name), Address:="somexcel.xlsx"
    End With
End Sub
```

It adds the picture, but not the hyperlink. When I run the sub by itself, it adds the picture and hyperlinks it.
But I need it to be in the form of a function. It can't be a button or anything like that. I have to be able to call it with =SomeFunction().

Comment: The description for the VB.NET tag specifically states that it should not be used got VBA questions. Please don't spam tags.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ah, sorry. I'm new, didn't know.

Comment: Functions called like formulas `=SomeFunction()` are not allowed to change cells or add hyperlinks. That is not possilble in Excel.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I was afraid that would be the case. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: No only a sub called by a button or shortcut can do that.

Comment: I'm sure there is a workaround. Can you explain why you believe this needs to be a function? Instead of a UDF, you may be able to use a `Worksheet_Change` event? If you can provide more context would be happy to try to help.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Unfortunate. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @urdearboy Of course. I made a small javascript page that lists all files in a directory. The files need to be drag-and-dropped into excel creating links to those files. I do that by adding a value to the draggable element which is an excel function. For now, it works, but only for regular text. I basically just drag =HYPERLINK("path") to a cell and it creates a link to that file.

Comment: hm. Not sure I follow. What do you mean adding a value to the draggable element? Are you talking about the formula parameter (which your function has none of)?

Comment: Is there a specific action that will always occur before you need to run the macro? The javascript is prob not relevant info here. But, it's also worth noting you can list all files in a directory into excel with VBA. So you can have the macro do that and then call end that sub with the sub here that you tried to link to the UDF

Comment: @urdearboy Yes, in the javascript i make the element draggable, then add a "ondragstart" event onto it. In the event, you can set its data (the string value which will be written into wherever you've dragged it to). You can drag this and drop it anywhere and it will write that value in there. So i made the value =HYPERLINK() and when i drop it into a cell, it creates a hyperlink. I even managed to make it create an image at that cell location but i can't add a hyperlink to it

Comment: hm. Sorry I know nothing about javascript so having a hard time translating this to just a excel problem. It's not clear to me when the problem stops being javascript and when it starts being excel. I don't know what you mean by dragging (from where to where?). Won't keep firing questions at you though. If you can strictly explain the steps in excel then ill try to understand one more time. If you have a gif recorder (like LiceCap) you can try to demonstrate the problem that way. Sometimes problems are easier to show than explain. But i'm also tired so may just be having a brain fart lol

Comment: @urdearboy The idea for this is that it's supposed to help when creating excel files with a lot of file links by creating a drag-and-drop interface from which you can just drop the link into wherever you need it to be. That main file shouldn't contain the folder structure. If all else fails, i'll just have to settle with coloring the cell unfortunately.

Comment: @urdearboy The problem is just in the excel. I just need it to hyperlink the image from a Function instead of a Sub. Currently i'm calling the Sub in the Function and it won't hyperlink it. However when i run the Sub by itself, it links the image. Specifically, the Hyperlinks.Add method won't work when called from anywhere but a Sub

Comment: What is the action directly before you would call the function? You may be able to use some other event based macro to call your sub. Instead of typing in the formula for example you could use a `Worksheet_Change` to do this.

Comment: ok last question - would you be typing the UDF into the cell **IF** you were allowed to call the sub from the function? If so, I can try to show a example of what I mean as a workaround as solution

Comment: @urdearboy Yes. If i can write it manually into the cell, everything else will work perfectly.

Comment: Is there a specific cell you would enter the formula? Or could it be any cell/

Comment: @urdearboy No other action except writing =SomeFunction() into the cell. The Worksheet_Change is going to be a lot of help, thank you. I'm very new to VB so even this is a great help! Thank you

Comment: @urdearboy Any cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of a `UDF` you can try to utilize a `Worksheet_Change` event that will call your `InsertPictureHyperlink()` macro. To ensure the macro does not fire anytime you change a cell, add a condition to **only** fire the macro when a certain keyword is entered. Here the keyword will be `AddHyperlinkedImage`

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target = "AddHyperlinkedImage" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
        InsertPictureHyperlink
        
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub InsertPictureHyperlink()

MsgBox "Macro enabled - add your code in this sub"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much! This will solve it i think.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry i'm as green as can be. Thank you again, this is a great help!

Comment: Sorry that took a while but we got there lol. I think too much info was shared so I didn't know where to focus. You should take a look at the other event based macros since they can be very useful.

Comment: I will, thank you. I just started with VBA yesterday but i have to have this done soon so it's kinda confusing.